# Filter files from directory vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, filter, get, directory

Straight to the question...I have files such as word documents with extension`(.doc)` and its respective sample files starting with `(.sample)`

Now I would like to load only the word documents..

I found the way as shown below to load the files but this loads all the files

Can anyone say me how do I filter these files while loading them ?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Dim files = Array.FindAll(Directory.GetFiles(mydir), Function(x) (Not x.StartsWith(".sample")))
```

This is my directory consists of files as said above:

[image]

Comment: Can you post some example filenames you're using to clarify?

Comment: @GregHNZ-I have updated it please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetFiles method returns filenames with the path that you specified **included**.

So if your files are in a folder `C:\working\`, your `mydir` variable will contain `"C:\working\"` and all of the results of GetFiles will be something like

```
"C:\working\.sample_filename.doc"
"C:\working\123797.doc"
```

So your `x.StartsWith` is always going to return false, because x always starts with `C:\`

Try this:

```
Dim files = Array.FindAll(Directory.GetFiles(mydir), Function(x) (Not x.StartsWith(mydir & ".sample")))
```

Note this assumes that your `mydir` variable ends with a `\` character. If not, add it in in the concatenation within the function.

Answer (score 3):

The way you use it, all the files are retrieved (paying the whole computational cost) and then they are filtered.

As stated in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Directory.GetFiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article, you can use a search pattern directly in file retrieval from your file system.

I suppose you could do something like that:

```
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(mydir,".doc*")
```

If you gave an example of filenames, perhaps I would give you the right filter to apply too.

Hope I helped!

Comment: This answer is much better than getting all the files then filtering them as it does it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   Dim files = Array.FindAll(Directory.GetFiles(mydir), Function(x) (Not Path.GetFileName(x).StartsWith(".sample")))
```